# ¿Cómo se establece Border-Radius en javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, variables

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para aprender mejor, trata de que yo pueda mediante un input colocar el valor del border-radius.
He creado un div, la idea es que el valor se guarde en varias variables y luego asignarles la función style de javascript, actualmente lo tengo todo por separado:

Breve ejemplo:

```
   d.style.borderTopLeftRadius = topLeft;
   d.style.borderTopRightRadius = topRight;
   d.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = bottomLeft;
   d.style.borderBottomRightRadius = bottomRight;
```

Pero lo que busco es que sea todo en uno:

```
d.style.borderRadius = topleft topright bottomLeft bottomRight;
```

la cosa es que no funciona, no sé si es por que la concatenación o otra cosa, directamente no tengo idea de como hacerlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los valores deben ir dentro de una cadena, puedes usar un [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para insertar las variables directamente:

```
d.style.borderRadius = `${topleft} ${topright} ${bottomLeft} ${bottomRight}`;
```